# Export geo node animations and materials

Tags: export, geometry-nodes, geometry

I created a simple sphere with faces being scaled by distance with geometry nodes.  In the geo node tree, I also applied two materials to the faces.  The material is not animated.

It's not exact, but is based off of this tutorial.  I'm doing something similar, but to the faces.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keKDABQfxQU&t=283s

Is there a way to export this to Maya or Unity with the animated faces and materials applied?

Comment: The only way I know is to export this in an Alembic format. But that probably won't help you in Unity either... But I can be wrong.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @quellenform I'm able to get the allembic to work in Unity, but this won't hold any material info.  However, based off the link Duarte Farrajota Ramos posted, the solution would be to created uv islands for the different materials and apply them in the other app.  So then now another question arises, how can you uv geometry nodes that are applied to a plane?  Just throwing that out there, but will do my research right now :)

Comment: That didn't take too long.  For anyone wondering this same question, here are two very helpful links.  It's also worth noting I'm in 3.0 and looks like 3.3 now has a uv unwrap node.

https://youtu.be/_zXbPRYpi5I
https://youtu.be/tqoIyfKuGK4

Comment: @JerryT Sounds good! Could you please write an answer to this and possibly make it without external links (Youtube, etc.). That would be awesome and very helpful for all who have a similar problem.

Comment: @quellenform Whoops, noob here :)  Thanks, reposted.

Comment: @JerryT Perfect, no problem, welcome to BSE! If your answer to your question led to a solution, please do not forget to mark it as "Accepted Answer" so that the question appears as solved. Well done!

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you! @quellenform

Comment: Also 100% credit to Bradley Animation for the video in the links above.

Answer (score 1):

Unwrapping objects procedurally:

1. First duplicate the object
2. Apply the modifier to the duplicated object
3. Now go into *Edit Mode* on that newly duplicated object
4. Select all faces and either project UV’s or unwrap fully
5. Go to the UV’d object's Data Properties > UV Maps and rename to something like "Test" for now.
6. Now select the original object. Go to its geo nodes panel and add the following nodes:
   a. *Object Info* node with the UV’d object as the source. Connect to *Transfer Attribute*
   b. *Transfer Attribute* node set to *Vector*, *Index*, *Face Corner*
   c. *Group Input* connected to *Transfer Attribute*
7. After you connect these nodes it will add an "Attribute" to the Geometry Node modifier.
   a. Click the little cross or plus sign to blank out the name and type in the name of the UV map you named "Test" previously.
8. Then connect these nodes to the group output.
9. A new "Attribute" field will be added to the Output Attributes rollout in the Geo Node modifier
10. Type in "UV"
11. Go to your shader node window and add an *Attribute* node with "UV" typed for the name.
    a.Connect that to your image and your image to the Base Color
12. Make sure in Geo Nodes under the right panel, Outputs > Attribute is set to *Face Corner*
13. To change the texture from repeating go to the image node and change from repeat to clip